# RandomAccessFile-like API for in-memory byte array?

Tags: java

I need to replace code using `RandomAccessFile` with one that uses in-memory byte buffer (such as `byte[]` or derivatives like `ByteArrayInputStream`). Is there some API (byte array wrapper?) that has interface similar to `RandomAccessFile`, with `seek()` and streamish `read()` which I could plug in one-to-one?

Comment: Unless you need write as well, `DataInputStream` can easily be wrapped to provide the `seek()` functionality and the rest is already there. Not a perfect solution but if all else fails, it is relatively painless to implement.

Comment: Can you use a temporary file instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) can do it:

- `read()` works the same.
- `seek(n)` can be replaced with `reset()` followed by `skip(n)`

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to introduce a new interface that has both `read()` and `seek()` methods.  No existing Java I/O interface (new or old) has such an interface.  Once you have this interface, you'll have to create two implementations: one that uses `RandomAccessFile` and another that uses `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest [Java NIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) (New I/O) check [this](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3837206/An-Introduction-to-Java-NIO-and-NIO2.htm) simple and small tutorial

Comment: Also good, but has the downside that the interface is quite different from RandomAccessFile. By building on top of DataInputStream, you get something that implements DataInput, and code that uses the RandomAccessFile as a DataInput doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: joriki, `DataInput` doesn't provide `seek()`, so a `RandomAccessFile` that is passed to a method that expects a `DataInput` will not be very seekable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
RandomAccessFile has many finale and native methods, so it cannot be overloaded.

I ended to create my own SeekableInputStream abstract class by stealing this one without readfully : https://github.com/samtools/htsjdk/blob/master/src/java/htsjdk/samtools/seekablestream/SeekableStream.java

I defined SeekableFileInputStream which uses RandomAccessFile.

I defined SeekableByteArrayInputStream, which is easy to define.
This class, is also able to get any InputStream, to transform it into a byte array, so this is a kind of cached stream.

Answer (score -1):

I happen to have one of these -- I uploaded it to http://home.arcor.de/joriki/seekable-byte-array.zip -- hope that helps.