# Correct ZIP implementation without I/O in Java

Tags: java, zip

Is there any Java library that implements the algorithms required to read a ZIP archive by finding the end of central directory record and using that to locate the central directory records and then the local file entries (local file header and local file data), without doing I/O?

Please refer to the [ZIP specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) for definition of such fields, if needed.

The reason for reading from the end of central directory is to be able to correctly uncompress files *such as* self extracting files (see [Winzip Self Extractor](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagese.htm) for an example), which have data before the actual ZIP contents that *may* contain sequences of bytes equal to existing signatures of ZIP headers.

By "without doing I/O" I mean that the ZIP contents exists as an array of bytes, and no disk or network access should be used to uncompress it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to read a byte array as if it were from a file.

```
byte[] zipData = . . .
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipData));
```

**EDIT**

Since the standard `ZipFile` implementation uses native code, it can't be used with a `ByteArrayInputStream`. However, you might be able to adapt one of the pure-Java implementations of `ZipFile`. One place to start is the [Android implementation](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/0c9612f9d7ff9fc0a61cc9eeb37acaabb7b28700/libcore/archive/src/main/java/java/util/zip/ZipFile.java). It doesn't do the job completely, as it uses `RandomAccessFile`. However, using the ideas in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897599/randomaccessfile-like-api-for-in-memory-byte-array) for an in-memory version of `RandomAccessFile`, you might be able to piece together everything you need.

Comment: ZipInputStream doesn't work as specified on the question. I know that for a fact, since I read its implementation.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - The main point of the answer is that `ByteArrayInputStream` can be used to read a byte array _as if_ you were reading from a file. If you know how to do what you want from a file, then you can use this to do what you want from a byte array without any I/O. If you don't know how to do what you want from a file, then I don't understand why you brought in the "without doing I/O" requirement at all--just ask what you really need to know.

Comment: I *have* asked what I need to know, in very precise terms. `ZipInputStream` doesn't do it, and `ZipFile` doesn't work with input streams, which makes your claim that `ByteArrayInputStream` let you work as if you were reading from a file plainly false. If you can show how I can work with `ZipFile` with a `ByteArrayInputStream`, *that* would certainly earn an accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - I updated my answer with another idea. Perhaps it's enough so you can put together what you need.

Comment: I truly thank you for your effort in answering the question, but that's as good as a "no". If I have to code significant parts of it, there are easier ways. I'm really looking for a reliable, well tested library that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Our SecureBlackbox includes [ZIP components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-zip.php) which operate with in-memory streams. I guess this is exactly what you are looking for.